# Add circle to map with carto.js and leaflet libraries

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, latitude-longitude, geometry

I have to show a circle on feature click on my layer.
When I try to create the circle I have this error: `Error: Invalid LatLng object: (41.961124103390674, NaN)`.

If I print the object before this error I can read: `Array [ 41.84664960937685, 12.008056640625 ]`.
I tried to write values separated but it doesn't work.

How is it possible?
Someone can help me? Thanks and sorry for my english

EDIT

I tried this solution:

```
layer.getSubLayer(1).on('featureClick', function (event, latlon, pos, data, index) {
var coord = {lat:data.lat, lng:data.lon};
console.log(coord)
L.circle(coord, {radius: data.distance}).addTo(map);
```

Error and log are the same...

EDIT 2

With this code

```
var coord = L.latLng(42,21);
var cerchio = L.circle(coord,{radius: data.distance});
     console.log(cerchio);
     cerchio.addTo(map);
```

I noticed that circle Object is correctly created, so the problem is on addTo(map) method.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to avoid confusion. Thank you. Check your [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44903639/revisions) history if you want to copy and paste the solution to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The correct way is

```
L.circle([data.lat, data.lon], data.distance, {}).addTo(map);
```

where `data.distance` is the radius of circle. Official doc's example `L.circle([50.5, 30.5], {radius: 200}).addTo(map);` seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Carto Docs](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/events#layer), the `latlon` argument in your `featureClick` callback contains:

> Array with the LatLng ([lat,lng]) where the layer was clicked.

Is that where you want the circle to be placed?  If so, use this line:

```
L.circle(latlon, {radius: data.distance}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Yes is that, but I already used 'latlon' and the result is always the same.

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(latlon);`?

Comment: `Array [ 41.94478317075675, 12.183837890625 ]`

Answer (score -1):

Add `1609*3`

```
var coord = L.latLng(42,21,1609*3);
```